# trouble printing after allocating memory

Tags: c

After using `malloc`, `name` gets printed but after allocating memory and typing in a `string`, `puts` doesn't print the string at all, neither does `printf`...why is this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main()
{
    char *name;
    int size;
    printf("enter the size if name below\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    name  =(char*) malloc(size * sizeof(char));//since my compiler returns pointr of type    void, you have specify whether (int*) or (char*)
    if (name== NULL)
    printf("memory allocation failed,,,\n");
    printf("%s\n",name);
    printf("enter name below\n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("name is\n%s", name);
    name = (char*)realloc(name, 100*sizeof(char));
    if (name == NULL)
    printf("failed\n");
    gets(name);
    getchar();
    puts(name);
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, `malloc/realloc` do *not* return `void`, they return `void*` which is perfectly capable of being implicitly cast to any other pointer type. It's a bad idea to do so explicitly in C since it can hide certain subtle errors.

In addition, `sizeof(char)` is *always* one, you do not need to multiply by it.

Thirdly, using `gets` is a very bad idea since there's no way to protect against buffer overflow. There are [much better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921) to do user input.

As to the specific problem, I suspect it's most likely still sitting around at the `getchar`. `gets` will get a line from the user (including the newline character) but, unless you enter another character (probably a full line if it's using line-based I/O), it will seem to hang. Check this by simply hitting <kbd>ENTER</kbd> *again* after you've entered the name.

Comment: To precise paxdiablo comment: Chars can be represented **internally** with **any** number of bits (ie, not always a multiple of 8!). But he's true: sizeof(char)==1 : "It is generally not safe for a programmer to presume to know the size of any datatype. For example, even though most implementations of C and C++ on 32-bit systems define type int to be 4 bytes, the size of an int could change when code is ported to a different system, breaking the code. **The exception to this is the char type, whose size is always 1 in any standards-compliant C implementation**." en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof

Comment: important precision from the same wikipedia: "sizeof is used to calculate the size of any datatype, measured in the number of bytes required to represent the type. **A byte in this context** is the same as an unsigned char, **and may be larger than 8 bits**, although that is uncommon.". Ie, sizeof() is not in bytes ! [although on most system it will be]

Answer (score 0):

Try either `fgets()` or `scanf()` at the place of `gets()`.It will work

Answer (score 0):

The program that you have posted causes `undefined behavior`. This is because of

```
printf("%s\n",name);
```

There is nothing in the variable `name` and you are trying to print the value in the allocated memory. First you need to assign some value to `name` before printing it.